# Convergence in topology finer than cocountable

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

> If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is finer than cocountable topology then convergence is trivial (convergent sequences are only the eventually constant).

I already proved that convergence in cocountable topology is trivial, but how can I extend this result to finer topologies?

Comment: If $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are topologies on $X$ such that $\tau \subseteq\tau'$ then any sequence that converges with respect to $\tau'$ will converge with respect to $\tau$. If sequences convergent with respect to $\tau$ are all eventually constant, so must be sequences convergent with respect to $\tau'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is *not* eventually constant. Then the set $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\wedge x_n\ne x\}$ is a countable set. Let $O=\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\wedge x_n\ne x\}^\complement$. Then $O$ belongs to the cocountable topology, and therefore $O\in\mathcal T$. Since $x\in O$, $O$ is then a neighborhood of $x$. But there are infinitely many $n$'s that don't belong to $O$ (since they belong to $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\wedge x_n\ne x\}$). This is impossible, since we are assuming that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$.

Comment: Why does $x\in O$?

Comment: The set $O$ was not correctly defined. It should have been $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\wedge x_n\ne x\}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized. You couldn't have explained it better, thank you very much :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the above problem.

1)Assume  $x_n \rightarrow x$ in a top. space, i. e.

for every neighborhood of $U$ of $x$ there

exists a $n_0$  s.t. $x_n \in U$ for $n\ge n_0$.

Assume $x_n \rightarrow x$ in the cocountable topology.

2)$U:=X $ \ {$x_n| x_n \not=x, n\in \mathbb{N}$}.

We have $x \in U$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

3 Since $x_n \rightarrow x$, there is a $n_0$ s.t. $x_n \in U$ for $n\ge n_0$.

4)This implies $x_n=x$ for $n\ge n_0$.